# Remove text / characters from clipboard using Applescript

Tags: macos, text, applescript, clipboard, automator

I have some text in my clipboard that always has the following structure

> text?text

For example:

> sampletextsampletext?acb=1&acb

I would like to create an Applescript (part of a Mac Shortcuts workflow) that grabs the clipboard, finds the ? and removes both the ? and all of the text after it. After, return it to the clipboard.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the clipboard.
2. Find the offset of `?`.
3. Trim the text (keep characters 1 to offset-1) and write it back.

   ```
   set theText to get the clipboard
   set questionMarkOffset to offset of "?" in theText
   set the clipboard to text 1 thru (questionMarkOffset - 1) of theText
   ```

Comment: That worked, thank you! What if I would like to remove the ? and everything left of it?

Comment: Here you go `set the clipboard to text (questionMarkOffset + 1) thru - 1 of theText`